# Column level grouping in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have to replicate one matrix table below is the dataset and details.

```
[![SELECT
   Flag.T
  ,Flag.C   
  ,SUBSTRING(Flag.Title,1,1) + Case CHARINDEX(' ',Flag.Title,1) WHEN 0 THEN ''
     ELSE SUBSTRING(Flag.Title,CHARINDEX(' ',Flag.Title,1)+1,1) END AS  Signn
FROM
  Flag
FULL OUTER JOIN
Mark on Mark.[Key] = Flag.[Key]
```

Table rows:

[image]

Design mode of matrix table here StatusAbbrevFrom =Signn and Title=T in data set column value

[image]

I need a preview of Matrix table should be like this:

[image]

How can I design same column group Matrix from scratch in ssrs?

Comment: Your column group design looks correct. Are you having trouble with the conditional colors or something else? It's not clear if you're asking a specific question or you just want a general walk-through.

Comment: @StevenWhite:Thanks for comment .Yes I want to general walk through how can i design from scratch in SSRS design panel?